# Angularjs directive set scope var in directive and access in controller

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am working on angularjs. I am facing an issue in directive.
I have set the `scope.user.name="amin shah"` on link/click event
and want to access this in controller how is this possible?

```
var dataSourceDirective = angular.module('mydirective', []);
dataSourceDirective.directive('dir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: true,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                    $scope.user.name ="amin shah";
                    $scope.$apply();
                    $('.sourceType_panel').hide();
                    $('#sourceType_1_panel').show();

            });
        }
    }
});
```

**controller** code

```
$scope.demo = function () {
      console.log($scope.user);`
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Isolated scope in your directive.
The given controller should be parent of this directive.

```
var dataSourceDirective = angular.module('mydirective', []);
dataSourceDirective.directive('dir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {user:"=user"},
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                    $scope.user.name ="amin shah";

            });
        }
    }
});
```

In html :

```
<div ng-copntroller='yourCtrl'>
<dir user="user"></dir>
</div>
```

In Controller you should initialize the `user`.

OR

you use [$broadcast & $emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) if the parent is controller.

Withing link function of directive you can use `$rootScope.$emit('user_name_update',user);`

And in the controller you can listen this event

```
$scope.$on('user_name_update',function(data){

   console.log(user) // its should give your updated `user` object
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should correct your link method and I think you shouldn't need child sope at there. So you should delete your scope bind in directive too. You can reach parent scope with link method.

```
    app.directive('dir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                    scope.user.name ="amin shah";
                    scope.$apply();

            });
        }
    }
});
```

and in your controller you can define scope variable like that:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.user = {
       name: ''
     }
  });
```

also you should add this directive to HTML :

```
<dir>Element</dir>
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
```

here is the working `plunkr` you should click **Element** than you can see your name from directive but in parent scope

https://plnkr.co/edit/umTdfukZ22hARoLjxdL3?p=preview